# shopping cart discount issues

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, coupon

We are running on magento 1.9.3.2 and usually know how to configure cart discount rules in 1.8 properly. In the new installation we have the following problems:

- when we add "**free shipping**" to the code and use it, it is not marked as used in the backend and be be reused
- When I use a specific code, again with free shipping (that is then properly applied) and return from the last onecheckout display to the cart and revoke the coupon code it is still applied, so **revocation does not work**
- when I define a discount with free shipping and zero product discount and use it it stays persistant for all consecutive purchases.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options that you'll want to make sure are checked when you are setting up a shopping cart price rule.

If you want to limit the usage, you'll want to:

- Require that end users have to enter in a coupon code.
- Limit the number of uses per coupon (such as 5 uses total or 50 uses total).
- Limit the uses per customer (i.e. to 1 or 5).

Please note that the usage limit is enforced for customers that are logged in only.

This is a feature of Magento.  If you want to us auto-generated coupon codes, you can do that, and then those codes will only be able to be used a single time.  The drawback is that you have to give each user a code.

I hope this helps...

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule in Magento 1.9]

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this magento shop is allowing guest users only. Does that mean, that the limitation will not work at all? Can this be also the reason for not marking the generated coupon code as "used"? best J

Comment: Correct...  Magento unfortunately doesn't know one guest user from another, so that won't be a limitation in the system.  Chalk it up as a "feature". :(

Comment: Hm,  what puzzles me is: we have only guests, If I DO NOT add the "free shipping" as per drop down box both unique generated codes and coupons without generated code work perfectly fine and are marked as used. ONLY when I tick the "free shipping" they do not expire